# Why is the table in my question not rendered correctly?

Tags: support, specific-question, formatting

I created [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/359364/70510) and added the following table to it:

```
|| EUR | GBP |
|-| - | - |
| EUR | 1 | 0.85 |
| GBP | 1.17   | 1 |
```

In the preview it is shown correctly but why is it not rendered correctly in the actual question? Is it simply a bug or is my syntax wrong?

**Preview:**
[image: table in preview]

**Actual Question:**
[image: table in actual question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it for you.
You just need to add a blank line above the table.

Could be a bug or a small difference in how the content is interpreted in the preview and in the actual question

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a bug to me since it is nowhere mentioned that you need this blank line (or I cannot find it).